# How to display the whole number only if it starts with two characters otherwise leave it blank. SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to display the whole number in a field if it starts with "AB" otherwise do not show/display the number.

[image: example]

Comment: Read about `LIKE`. Probably something like `... WHERE TheNumberColumn LIKE 'AB%'`. Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing code of how you display this (since you wrote you need to display it to the field) so i can't answer you with actual code but here is solution.

If you want to select only rows which `column1` starts with `AB` then use `LIKE` function. So condition at selecting command is `Select * from yourtable where column1 LIKE 'AB%'`

If you already selected and displayed data, let's say in `datagridview`, and you want to fill `textbox` with string that contains `AB` then you would go through all rows at specific column and look for it with `string.Contains("AB");`

So basically you put this command in `foreach loop` and you have it.

Comment: The OP won't be able to use a LIKE to filter for the desired records. That will remove rows from the results rather than display results that don't match the pattern.

Comment: He can use the second one so i wrote both solutions

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. You can use a LIKE, just not in the WHERE clause.

```
;WITH testdata AS (
    SELECT 'aw12354' AS val UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'a12b344' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'AB11111' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '11AB111' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '11111AB' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'ab22222'
)
SELECT
      CASE WHEN val LIKE 'AB%' THEN val ELSE NULL END AS valFull 
    , CASE WHEN val LIKE 'AB%' THEN SUBSTRING(val,3,len(val)) ELSE NULL END AS valNums
FROM testdata
;
```

You can also use CLR to build a regex solution, but that is a *LOT* more involved.